I am trying to figure out how to incorporate a date range restriction while using the MIN function in SQL
I have a list of order dates for various vendors on specific items. I want to be able to pull the MIN orderdate but also have the min order date be within a specific date range (i.e. first day of last month thru end of next month).
Dataset:



Item
Vendor
Order Date
Notes




1
ABC
1/1/2020
<-MIN ORDERDATE for item and vendor


1
ABC
4/6/2022



1
ABC
6/6/2023



1
ABC
6/6/2024



1
ABC
8/8/2024



1
ABC
8/20/2024



1
DEF
8/4/2024



1
DEF
9/1/2024



1
DEF
9/14/2024



1
DEF
9/20/2024



1
DEF
10/9/2024



1
DEF
12/12/2024



2
ABC
11/11/2021
<=MIN ORDERDATE for item and vendor


2
ABC
3/3/2023



2
ABC
10/10/2023



2
ABC
8/1/2024



2
DEF
8/2/2024
<-MIN ORDERDATE for item and vendor


2
DEF
8/7/2024



2
DEF
9/4/2024



2
DEF
10/1/2024




I want the query, that is using the date range of (8/1/2024-10/30/2024), to  produce the folllowing results below. Even thouhgh there are orderdates that fall within the range, i dont want them included in the results unless the minimum order dates for that vendor and item fall with the date range).



Item
Vendor
Earliest Order




1
DEF
8/4/2024


2
DEF
8/2/2024



SELECT ITEM, VENDOR, MIN(ORDERDATE::timestamp) AS "Earliest Order"
FROM ORDERS
WHERE
ORDERDATE between date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - interval '1 month' and  date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '2 month' -interval '1 day'
Group by 1,2


"With the query I am using, I am getting this order in my results, but I dont want to" It is not clear which "this order" is. Your question would be easier to answer if you include 1) your table definition 2) sample data for everything in the query 3) your desired results.  Present your data using the table formatting to make it easy to read. Ideally, set it all up in dbfiddle. Also, please note which database you are using.

Hi @Schwern apologies I am not familiar on how to use the dbfiddle. I did edit the question to include a dataset. I hope this helps clarify my question. I appreciate your help!

I think what you want is only the results HAVING a minimum order date in the range, is that right?

hi @JasonGoemaat yess!!

The problem with your query is that you filtered the orders before find the minimum order date. You have to compute the minimum order date, then group the result by item and vendor and finally filter on earliest order date, something like this:
SELECT ITEM, VENDOR, MIN(ORDERDATE) AS "Earliest Order"
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY ITEM, VENDOR
HAVING MIN(ORDERDATE) BETWEEN date('month', CURRENT_DATE) - interval '1 month'
AND date('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '2 month' - interval '1 day'
Check the correct syntax for date functions regarding your DBMS

Are you perhaps using PostgreSQL? If so then please add that tag, or add a tag for whatever the DBMS is that aplies. The SQL tag by itself is quite useless, it needs to be accompanied with a tag for the product.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. Also, please read the description of the [tag:sql] tag carefully.

Filter by min(orderdate).
where filters row-by-row and does not allow aggregate functions, use having instead. having filters on the grouped (aggregated) data.
select
  item, 
  vendor, 
  min(orderdate) AS "Earliest Order"
from orders
group by 1, 2
having min(orderdate) between
  date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - interval '1 month' and
  date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '2 month' - interval '1 day';

